# Android. Draw bitmap between two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to make application which will have background and some picture with alpha channel in front. Between them i want to draw bitmap/animation.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

That is easy. You can use FrameLayout as the root layout and set a background to it. Then add two more LinearLayouts which fill the screen. In the first you may add your animated views like ImageView, while in the second you can insert an ImageView or ImageButton with a transparent image in it.

There are many other ways to do this like using a custom view for your animated layer etc. Check my example here: [How can I use the animation framework inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893)