# android traceview

Tags: android, debugging, android-traceview

I made an application and I wanted to see if I can improve performance by running a traceview on a certain activity + it's background tasks.

[This link points](http://i45.tinypic.com/11weufl.png) to an image from traceview. As you can see there are 2 colors that are taking the most time + processor.

- The blue color is from `drawBitmap`. (I use a header logo, a repeating
  header background and another background that repeats over the whole
  screen, all described in **XML layout** file).
- The green color is something called `dalvik/system/VMDebug.startGC ()V`

My questions:

1. Can I do something to make this drawBitmap less expensive ? (I would
   however like to keep all images on the screen)
2. What is this VMDebug thing? Can't seem to find much about it via
   Google

Comment: Have you found some hints relating to your question 1.? Having the same problem here...

Comment: I didn't find any good answers to my problem. I decided to just let this one go. I guess bitmap drawing is just way more expensive than some of my other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be able to optimize your bitmap drawing,(you mention a background that is drawn repeatedly)

VMDebug is the dalvik debug monitor 
the startGC() function is called to start garbage collection

Comment: But how can I optimize the bitmap drawing? It's done in android itself as I'm just working with XML layouts.

Also: is this always taking so much time, or just now when I'm debugging?

Answer (score 0):

1)[Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856550/android-fastest-way-to-draw-a-bitmap-to-canvas) this answer to make drawBitmap less expensive

2)VM-specific debug features. Though this class and many of its members are public, this class is meant to be wrapped in a more friendly way for use by application developers. On the Android platform, the recommended way to access this functionality is through the class android.os.Debug.

[More Details](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-446/android/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.0_r2/docs/reference/dalvik/system/VMDebug.html)