# Set image for android object

Tags: android, image, object, set

This is what my vegitables.java looks like

```
 public class Vegitable extends Context {
    String type;
    int side, position;

 public Vegitable(int side, int position) {
    if(side < 3 && side > 0 && position < 3 && position > 0) {
        this.side = side;
        this.position = position;
        this.setRand();
    }
  }
  public String getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

   public  boolean setRand() {
      Random rr = new Random();
      switch(rr.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1) {

        case 1:
            this.type = "Onion";
            break;
        case 2:
            this.type = "Pepperoni";

            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In my Main.Activity i want to randomly generate eighter an onion or a pepperoni. (Like this:)

```
public void spawn() {

    if(this.vegi.length > 30)
        return;

    Random r = new Random();

    if(r.nextInt(this.spawnRotationMax - 1) + 1 != 1)
        return;

    this.vegi[vegiNum] = new Vegitable(r.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1,r.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1);
    //this.vegi[1].getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charab);


    if (vegi[vegiNum].type.equals("Pepperoni")){}

    Toast.makeText(GameAcvitiy.this, this.vegi[vegiNum].getType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    vegiNum++;
```

My question is : Where and how can i give my vegi objects an image so i can see and use them in my Main.Activity ? (I want to let em collide later on)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put this into a game (sounds like it from what you mentioned about them colliding), then you should look in to using Bitmaps to render the graphics.  In that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856550/android-fastest-way-to-draw-a-bitmap-to-canvas) should be helpful.  Any generic Android game tutorial will help with this.  You could load the images normally, or from a sprite sheet.

If you just want to display the images inside a layout (such as a LinearLayout or a ListView), look in to using [ImageViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Comment: Could you make an example (with the given code) or give me a link to a good tutorial ?  Would appreciate

Comment: If you're looking for the first approach, you can check out http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099. Upvote/mark as best answer if it helps

Comment: I think we are talkin in different directions. I want my vegi objects to have a bitmap. So you can see the objects on the screen after i called them .