# Canvas - null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image

Sometimes, I am getting NullPointerException in the line. Please let me know how to correct this. At the time of error, I have checked the possibility for the null value in variable backgoundImage. The variable backgoundImage is not null.

```
  canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0    , null);
```

### Code:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        while (isRunning) { 
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();    
            screenCenterX = dWidth / 2; 
            screenCenterY = dHeight / 2;  

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if(backgoundImage == null){ 
                try { 
                    Log.i("DragDropCheck", "----------------backgoundImage is null--------");
                    backgoundImage = getAssetImage(getContext(),"backgroundhomepage");
                    canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }else{ 
                canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);
            } 
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (imagePublishDone) {
                if(!welcomeDone){                       
                 welcomeDone=true;
                }
                moveImageInEllipticalPath();
            } else {
                initialImagePublish();
            } 
            centreReached = false;
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

### logcat:

```
07-09 22:40:18.689: E/AndroidRuntime(8794): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-621
07-09 22:40:18.689: E/AndroidRuntime(8794): java.lang.NullPointerEception
07-09 22:40:18.689: E/AndroidRuntime(8794): at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.run(DragDrop.java:645)
07-09 22:40:18.689: E/AndroidRuntime(8794): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: its your `canvas` that is null.

Comment: Do you have tested 
`if(canvas!=null)` too?

Comment: Give us the exact line , or else there are too many assumptions in place .

Comment: Try to see this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921412/surfaceholder-lockcanvas-returning-null

Comment: This is the line where is get error canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null); This comes in the else part of the if condition

Comment: @iappmaker since you suggest image is not null only possibility according to your suggestion is canvas being null. check if(canvas==null)

Comment: you may be right, but how come the canvas be null.

Comment: @iappmaker make sure canvas is null by checking it then report back.

Comment: I have tested. Canvas is null. How to resolve this ?

Comment: @iappmaker then my guess to your previous question hold's good your image is null and what your suggesting is wrong. there is no way both not being null and you get npe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33154/discussion-between-iappmaker-and-raghunandan)

Comment: Hope the bug is related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38658

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is that the `canvas` variable is `null`. You should manage that specific case to avoid executing code when the `ourHolder.lockCanvas()` call returns `null` (also, you should check that your `ourHolder` variable isn't null before executing the `while` loop).