# need help, pls say the reason for nullpointer exception even though everything instantiated in a calss and error is in drawCircle method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-canvas

I need to find out what is missing for a drawCircle method on surfaceview.
calling lockcanvas after calling `getholder()` in `onCreate` and also tried same from the method but I got error.

here is mainactivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Main2Activity contentView;
    Tester tester;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("App", "App launched");

        tester = new Tester(this);
//        GameView gameView = new GameView(this);
        Log.d("App", "set calling.");

        setContentView(tester);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("App", "onResume");

        tester.resume();
    }
}
```

Here the method to draw circle:

```
public class Tester extends SurfaceView {

Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
boolean b;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public Tester(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("App", "in other context.");

//        canvas = new Canvas();
//        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
//        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
//        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
//        setWillNotDraw(false); //this line is very important!

    }

/*
    public void run() {
        Log.d("App", "in running.");

        synchronized (canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()) {
            while (b) {

                drawing();
                Log.d("App", "drawing passed");
            }
        }
    }
*/
    private void drawing() {
        Log.d("App", "posting.");
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        synchronized (canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()) {

                paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                canvas.drawCircle(100, 200, 20, paint);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }
    void resume() {
        b = true;
        drawing();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference

I failed to find what can be mistaken, what is not instantiating on this simple code snippet?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: please mention the reason to nullPointer exception. Im asking to know it. :)

Comment: Your _canvas_ is null

Comment: calling "canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();"  how else to initialize?

Comment: It is null. everyone knows and you repeated in that answer. say the reason or a way around to get rid of it.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921412/surfaceholder-lockcanvas-returning-null

Answer (score 0):

**As you mentioned in your comment:**

> please mention the reason to nullPointer exception. Im asking to know it. :)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference
```

Your `LogError` is clearly saying that the object of `Canvas` is null, which means that instance of `Canvas` that you using in your code did not exist or is null.

Look here:

```
here --> canvas.drawCircle(100, 200, 20, paint);
```

The reference of `Canvas` here `canvas` is null, try to init it.

Comment: But i am instantiating it by calling "canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();"
maybe missing something, how else can i do it? calling "new Canvas" showed no effect. All commented code in constructor was tested. Thanks.