# Android Development: Game background loop

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, game-loop

I'm developing a 2d Game using `Canvas/Surfaceview` and have a problem with thread.
So what I want to accomplish is something in the background that is for example:
for each second `SpawnEnemy()` or ticking seconds or attacking.

I tried Thread.wait but that just cause pain and make my game 2fps.

here is my gameLoop:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
       static final long FPS = 20;
       private GameView view;
       private boolean running = false;

       public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
             this.view = view;
       }

       public void setRunning(boolean run) {
             running = run;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
             long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
             long startTime;
             long sleepTime;
             while (running) {
                    Canvas c = null;
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                           c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                           synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                                  view.onDraw(c);
                           }
                    } finally {
                           if (c != null) {
                                  view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                           }
                    }

                    sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    try {
                           if (sleepTime > 0)
                                  sleep(sleepTime);
                           else
                                  sleep(10);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
             }
       }
}
```

So I want something that is ticking in the background (seconds) that doesn't thread.wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your thread run the game normally about 60fps, see this example: [How can I use the animation framework inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893)

If you want for each second to do something then you either count frames in onDraw(), on each 60th frame do it, or if you need a greater precision then in each onDraw() check the system time and do something when a second has elapsed.

You should also consider using two methods one for drawing onDraw() and another for the game logic which are called from your thread.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for something to run in background