# Canvas and bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a canvas and I am drawing bitmap into it and moving that bitmap using onTouchEvent method. My problem is that the bitmap I move sometimes go out of the canvas region so how to solve this problem related to boundry of canvas. Please help me out on this and Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the sound of it seems to be more of coding issue, can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move the finger over the screen, you set the x,y drawing coordinates for your bitmap. Since you can know the size of the canvas from onSizeChanged method, you just need to make an if statement which will change the drawing coordinates of this bitmap only if the finger is within the area you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't find onSizeChanged method on Android Developer site. Could you please give the link where I can study about onSizeChanged method.

Comment: Check these examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893

Answer (score 0):

From the distance of current position and the base position calculate from your algorithm, you could able to manage this problem. It's only your algorithm problem.

Comment: I am asking is there any method which can set the canvas region so that we can draw the bitmaps upto that region only.

Comment: No, there is no such method that can do it for you. You have to do it by yourself.