# Water Ripple Effect in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use water ripple effect in my application, which effect continue in touch area repeatedly,I have gone to may sample code available in site,but ripple seems  pixelated.

Can any one please help me ,to implement live water ripple effect?.I found difficult to implement it.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44547/2d-water-with-dynamic-waves

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326039/live-wallpaper-water-ripple-effect

Comment: thanks...Do you know of any possible examples of how to do something like this in OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Salaam
I found this project, and it worked for me. it shows water ripple effect in One activity.
https://codeload.github.com/esteewhy/whater/zip/master

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.