# Animated Background in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, animated

I'm develeoping a game by android andengine.I wanna create animated background for menu scene.How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java` from andengine for an animated background. Just attach some buttons to it and you will have your menu scene with animated background.

[image: AutoParallaxBackgroundExample]

Answer (score 3):

Create a Scene with the animation any way you like and use HUD (a special kind of child Scene) to put the menu items on top. See this thread:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/hud-t2355.html

Answer (score -2):

The Answer that was given Here should be what you're looking for:
[How can I use the animation framework inside the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/)

> The Android animation class applies to objects such as views and layouts. The canvas is just a surface for drawing which is either part of a View or linked to a bitmap. In onDraw in a custom view only one frame is drawn at the time until next invalidate is called, which means that you have to draw your animation frame by frame. Here is an example of bouncing ball which rotates, which you may find useful.