# how to make this UI?

Tags: android, user-interface

So I've been looking around for days now and I can not find any tutorials on how to make a UI similar to this.

[image]

I want to do something similar to this where the buttons are intents and go to my activities instead of the home screen activities(phone, market, contacts, etc). Does anyone have any idea on how to start this?

Comment: this is done using opengl/renderscript, also i believe its called a "carousel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is complicated because it uses 3D camera transformation, it is not really for beginners but you can have a go at it:

[Android-3D-Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

Comment: Well I have a few months to work on this so I think I can do it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a custom view with a simple array of objects and a formula for their position and size. Here is how to do animation in a custom view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893