# Linking nested SurfaceView class inside xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, surfaceview

I have a class inside a class that extends SurfaceView like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    SurfaceTest mySurface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.surface);
        mySurface = (SurfaceTest) findViewById(R.layout.surface);
        mySurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // ... some code ...
        return true;
    }
    public class SurfaceTest extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder myHolder;

        public SurfaceTest(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            myHolder = getHolder();
        }

        public SurfaceTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            myHolder = getHolder();
        }

        public SurfaceTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            myHolder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                if (!myHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas();
                //...some code...
                myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**surface.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.example.testsurfaceview.MainActivity.SurfaceTest
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have an error in Graphical Layout of this xml file saying

```
"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.testsurfaceview.MainActivity.SurfaceTest"
```

One possible solution that worked for me was to create new class for `SurfaceTest` class and then using `com.example.testsurfaceview.SurfaceTest` in xml file.

But the problem again is I use a lot of information from `onTouch` event which is used to draw on canvas in `run()` method. This is the reason I implemented `SurfaceTest` class inside `MainActivity`

So I have two choices right now:

1) make xml work for nested SurfaceTest class
2) create new SurfaceTest class and pass all the info obtained in `onTouch` using an Intent.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Create a different class file named as `SurfaceTest` in your package and then add it into your xml file. It will surely work. Add the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` into your `Surface View class`.

Comment: so, I put all 'variables' and 'onTouch' event in different 'SurfaceTest' class... okay..lets see.. I'll be right back to let you know the result. :) Thanks for the suggestion @Karan

Comment: I'm stuck at one more poblem while implementing the above setup, As you said I created a new different class `SurfaceTest`, and in `MainActivity` I declared `SurfaceTest mySurface;` and in onCreate() `mySurface = new SurfaceTest(this);` but what about `mySurface.setOnTouchListener(this);` where to put this now? Sorry I'm not very much familiar with Android Programming.

Comment: add the SurfaceTest class into your MainActivty xml file(for which region u need surface object movement) & remove all declaration of SurfaceTest from MainActivity class.

Comment: go through this. It might be useful for your problem :::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938822/how-can-i-use-the-animation-framework-inside-the-canvas/4946893#4946893

Comment: I found a way using SurfaceHolder.Callback.. It worked till now, though I have not finished my project...thank you for your help..@Karan