# How to move Image after zooming in android

Tags: java, android, pinchzoom, zooming

I just need your help about how we can move our images when after  zooming it. I have done all rest of the things but only facing problem with moving images while zooming and get back to their normal size ? Please help me 
here is my code;

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.saeed.zooming;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView iv;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private float scale = 1f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener()); 
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.

            SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));

            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to move image like floating button ?? this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946893

Comment: Noop I have to move images only when we perform zoom on finger..

Comment: you want a zoom effect or move image after zoom?

Comment: Nest your `ImageView` in `HorizontalScrollView` and `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [MultiTouchLibrary](https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views) . It will fulfill your need This library provide you below functionality

1. Rotate
2. Scale Image (Pinch to zoom)
3. Move

Comment: I will check & try it

Comment: Did you get your answer ?